# SQL statement inside an SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I want this statement to return the systems where there are more than two stations, I got this far but I don't know what to do next. All this does it return every system with a regionID less than 1100001. Am I onto the right idea at least?

```
SELECT DISTINCT mapSolarSystems.regionID,solarSystemID,solarSystemName,x,z,security 
FROM mapSolarSystems 
WHERE mapSolarSystems.regionID <11000001  
AND 
2 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stations,mapSolarSystems
 WHERE mapSolarSystems.solarSystemID=stations.systemid)
```

Comment: Use having will help solve this problem, better have some data to explain the result.

Comment: How would I use that? Don't I still need to count every stationid entry that shares the same systemID in that?

Comment: what is the link between stations and mapSolarSystems?

Comment: I tried SELECT DISTINCT mapSolarSystems.regionID,solarSystemID,solarSystemName,x,z,security FROM mapSolarSystems,stations WHERE mapSolarSystems.regionID <11000001 HAVING COUNT( stations.systemid) >2  but that didnt work

Comment: Sorry i messed up the tags. The link between stations and mapSolarSystems is that mapSolarSystems.solarSystemID is linked to stations.systemid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mapSolarSystems.regionID,solarSystemID,solarSystemName,x,z,security 
FROM mapSolarSystems m
join stations s on m.solarSystemID = s.systemid
WHERE mapSolarSystems.regionID <11000001  
AND select COUNT(*) FROM stations >2
```

OR like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
mapSolarSystems.regionID,solarSystemID,solarSystemName,x,z,security 
FROM mapSolarSystems m
join (select sistemId ,count(systemid) from station group by sistemId having 
      count(sistemId) > 2) X on m.solarSystemID = X.systemid
WHERE mapSolarSystems.regionID <11000001
```

Comment: I have edited to a new vesion please see if this work better :)

Comment: Anyway, if you find my answer useful please upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT m.regionID,solarSystemID,solarSystemName,x,z,security FROM mapSolarSystems m join stations s on m.solarSystemID = s.systemid WHERE m.regionID <11000001 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stations) >2